# ag grid pagination not working, initially making server call twice

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Clicking on search button on the page will return result from server call and should display that in the ag grid.
Each click pagination details are seinding server will return only that much records to client.

Implemented ag grid but grid is not loading after clicking on search. Can you help me to figure out where I'm doing wrong.

### This is the html, grid section and search button.

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" >
   <div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="category">Category</label>
         <select  class="form-control"
            (change)="getSubCategories($event.target.value)"
            formControlName="catCode"   >
            <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categoryMaster" value="{{category.catCode}}">{{category.catDesc}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="rowData.length > 0">  
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-fresh"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"    
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [datasource] = "dataSource"
        enableColResize
        enableSorting
        enableFilter
        rowSelection="single"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

### Component

```
export class ISearchComponent {
    myForm: FormGroup;
    rowData: Array<IncidentHeaderModel> = new Array<IncidentHeaderModel>();
    gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        context: {},
        rowModelType: 'pagination',
        enableServerSideFilter: true,
        paginationPageSize: 10

    };

    //defining the headers
    columnDefs:any[] = [
        {headerName: 'Status', field: 'incidentStatus.value'},
        {headerName: 'Category', field: 'categoryMast.catDesc'},
        {headerName: 'Sub Category', field: 'subCategoryMast.subCatDesc'},
        {headerName: 'Location', field: 'location.locName'},
        {headerName: 'Time', field: 'incidentTime'},
        {headerName: 'Delay(Hrs)', cellRenderer:this.getDelayInHours}

    ];


    constructor(private masterDataService:MasterDataService,private http: Http) {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        'catCode'   : new FormControl()

    }
```

//when this data source get invoked

```
   dataSource = {
       pageSize: 10,
        getRows: (params: any) => {
          console.log("here dataSource")
                this.searchIncident(params.startRow, params.endRow); // returns json from server
                var rowsThisPage = this.rowData;
                var lastRow = -1;
                if (rowsThisPage.length <= params.endRow) {
                    lastRow = rowsThisPage.length;
                }
              params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }
     }
```

//server call and returns the json data.

```
searchIncident(start:number, end:number){


  myJson['firstResult'] = start;
  myJson.maxResult = this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize;

   this.http.post(AppUtils.INCIDENT_SEARCH, this.myForm.value, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res=>{
             this.rowData = res.json().result;
     console.log("@@@@" +JSON.stringify(this.rowData));
         }, err=>{             
         });

    }
}
```

### Tried solution(not working)

invoking the grid on search button click like this

```
 private search() {
     this.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(this.dataSource);
   }
```

I had added data source to enable server side pagination, then how can I invoke that  data source ?

***Any help in ag-grid pagination ? How to load data source ?***

added plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qIeONaAe4INyTuZTGAOK?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

Comment: any response would be good :)

Comment: There's an example of how to do it here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: You are using dataSource and rowData together. Try to remove the rowData.

Answer (score -2):

I think you will have to import the ag-grid inside @ngmodules root module

inside import

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ // put all your components / directives / pipes here

    ],
    imports: [ // put all your modules here
       ag-grid //for example
    ],
    providers: [ // put all your services here

    ],
    bootstrap: [ // The main components to be bootstrapped in main.ts file, normally one only
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

Comment: That all is add grid was working fine, I had tried adding pagination. Once data source is added then its not executing that data source.